# What's the best signing up a user through social login?

Tags: mobile-application, signup-signon, social-media, sign-in

I'm working on a project whereby both email and phone number is required from the user.

The user is able to sign up by email or through their social account. From my understanding of social sign ups is that not only it makes the process quicker (instead of using passwords) to authenticate a user, it also allows the application to capture the user's full name and email address.

Now there are two ways I can go about this if the user goes with social sign up,

1. Goes to the home/main page directly. The user will need to add their mobile number later in the profile page.
2. The user will need to fill in their mobile number in a 'Create Account' form for example. Full name and email address will be auto-populated.

What's the best way to approach this sign up the process? Or if there's a better way to go about this?

I hope that my question is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Social Media Log-in gives you access to different type of account data depending on the service used. For example:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Given that the current behavior of websites is some combination of:

1. Click social media login
2. Select, Enter or Automatic login for already logged-in services
3. Give consent for the app to access the social media
4. Instant login with no further info asked

I would consider asking for phone right after the user is successfully logged in. Asking user to enter phone before logging in would detract from the benefits of instant login. Moreover, capturing users instantly can also give you an opportunity for followup via email (for those who exit in the phone number step).

Comment: Makes sense. I'll go with the approach of asking the user to enter their mobile number after login. Thank you!